# Why won't this span hide and why is it showing up as #text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a span tag with two spans included inside. It looks like this:

```
<span>
    <span style="display:none;">Title</span>
    <span class="the_title">Title </span>
</span>
```

The first span and second span have different purposes which aren't really addressed in this question.
When I print the span as a whole to the console, it prints it correctly. However, if I try to print the elements inside, it is different.

Imagine, that the parent span is `this` in javascript. Using:

```
console.log(this.childNodes[0]);
```

results in:

```
<span style="display:none;">Title</span>
```

However,

```
console.log(this.childNodes[1]);
```

results in:

```
#text
```

Also

```
$(this.childNodes[1]).hide();
```

does nothing.

I want to hide the second span has a whole.

Comment: Because `childNodes` also includes textnodes, like the ones between your elements that you can't see on the screen. Try `children` instead.

Comment: Also, with jQuery ... `$(this).children().eq(1).hide()`

Comment: Not sure why I am being downvoted. I feel like I've explained the issue, the code and what I have done well. Even if this is some duplicate, I don't understand why my intentions are seen with malice. People are bound to make duplicate threads, one shouldn't be punished for it.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking at is a [text node.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) It's the actual text (or in this case, whitespace) between the tags.

Check out what happens when you look at more children:

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('span');
console.log(parent.childNodes[0].toString());
console.log(parent.childNodes[1].toString());
console.log(parent.childNodes[2].toString());
console.log(parent.childNodes[3].toString());
```

```html
<span>
    <span style="display:none;">Title</span>
    <span class="the_title">Title </span>
</span>
```

You can get only actual elements using [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children):

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('span');
console.log(parent.children[0].toString());
console.log(parent.children[1].toString());
console.log(parent.children[2]);
```

```html
<span>
    <span style="display:none;">Title</span>
    <span class="the_title">Title </span>
</span>
```

Comment: This is a very detailed response.